# Why is the present-perfect tense used in this sentence (he might not have died)?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

> Had he taken his doctor's advice, he might not have died.

Comment: Do you think it is wrong?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey May I know what's wrong with this sentence? Isn't "Had he taken" another expression of "If he had taken"?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking about.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Do you have any advice about how to modify my question?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'm a newcomer here and thanks for your advice!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey and OP, there's no present perfect in this sentence. Here, "have" is the base form because it follows "might", not present at all. If it were present, it would be "has" because of the subject "he".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is written using the **3rd conditional** and the structure is:

**if + past perfect**, ... **would + have + past participle**.

We can use other modals (for example *might*, *could*, *should*) instead of *would* in the main clause of a sentence in the third conditional: If he had taken his doctor's advice, he *might have* survived.

1. If he had taken his doctor’s advice, he might not have died.
2. Had he taken his doctor’s advice, he might not have died.

version 2 uses inversion for emphasis (if he had  —> had he)